# Is there a better way to express "I will give it a try"

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I was told that it is possible to use: "Я попробую" when referring to "i will try" (to answer the question). I know that the verb: "попробовать" means "to try". Is there some other phrase/s that could be used and that is/are perhaps more commonly used when want to say that I will try to answer the question (give it a try)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually **я попробую** *is* the best translation. **Попробовать** means to try tentatively. "Trying" as in "making an effort" is better expressed by different verbs, **постараться** or **попытаться**. One is for sustained effort, the other one is more all-or-nothing, but still different from **попробовать** which is more about seeing what happens.

Comment: I agree, this is one of those cases that are better translated in slightly different words than original. "I will give it a try" closer to word-to-word translation would be "я сделаю (одну/некую) попытку". (A try - in English here is a noun.) But in English it is kind of idiomatic phrase (they do not care much that this will be exactly *one* try). "Я попробую" is the best counterpart in Russian by frequency of usage. Prefix по- changes the verb into perfective aspects and hints to single try only.

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying (я старался) to answer this question myself over the years.  Here's what I came up with:-

Я попробую = I will try - i.e. give it a go (проба = a trial, a sample)

Я постараюсь = I will try - i.e. make an effort, be diligent (старание = diligence, effort)

Я попытаюсь = I will try - i.e. give it everything, torture myself to do it (пытать = to torture)

Hope this helps

Comment: Etymology's explanatory power is limited in general, and here, you're putting the cart before the horse in etymologising *попытаться*. *-пыт-* is the root for asking or finding out. Hyper-literally, *пытать* means to get answers out of someone; nothing about the word itself suggests inflicting pain, that meaning is secondary and somewhat metaphorical. Likewise,*пытаться* is not about "giving it everything". It can be that too, but primarily, it's about going in without knowing if your attempt will succeed or not.

Comment: Thanks for that correction Nikolay.  As you can probably gather, I am trying (я стараюсь) to piece the Russian language together without a proper teacher and it's easy to make wrong assumptions!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said here, one can try (можно постараться) to come up with even less obligatory modalities. Both  ***стараться*** and ***пытаться***  can be regarded as verbs of indefinite commitment, though this semantical trait is not obvious.

Е.g. one can dodge obligations with phrases like:

***посмотрим***

***подумаю***

***[смотря] по обстоятельствам***

***как пойдёт***

***как фишка / карта ляжет***

***как звёзды сложатся***

Basically, any future forms with ***по-*** can be rendered as a future of uncertain modality (indefinite commitment).